# What is this JSON-like data format(delimited by line break)?

Tags: json, string, format

```
"someIndex"
{
    "someOtherIndex"
    {
        "someKey"        "someValue"
        "someOtherKey"           "someOtherValue"
    }
}
```

Found some configuration files in a game and there seems to be a data format here, but I have no idea what it's called

Comment: what is the extension of the file...you can star looking from there

Comment: http://ndjson.org/ ??

Comment: extension is .txt and NDJSON is not correct

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/KeyValues

It's a special format of valve, basically